# Can't sort table by model's property (accessor set)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-tables2

I can't sort table by it's models property. I know that I should set accessor in the column so `django-tables2` knows what field to process but it does not work.

This is the table:

```
class ScansTable(tables.Table):
    site = tables.columns.Column(accessor='occurence.site', verbose_name='Site')
    url = tables.columns.TemplateColumn("""<a href="{{ record.occurence.url }}">{{ record.occurence.url|truncatechars:20 }}</a>""",
                                        accessor='occurence.url', verbose_name='Url')
    price = tables.columns.TemplateColumn(u"""{{ record.price }} €""")
    date = tables.columns.Column(accessor='date',order_by='date')
    time = tables.columns.Column(accessor='time',order_by='time')
    class Meta:
        model = Scan
        fields = ('date', 'time', 'site', 'url', 'valid', 'price')
        attrs = {'id': 'cans_table',
                 'class': 'table',}
```

This is the Scan model:

```
class Scan(models.Model):
    occurence = models.ForeignKey('Occurence', related_name='scans')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name='Price')
    valid = models.BooleanField(default=True,verbose_name='Valid')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{} {} {} {}'.format(self.occurence, self.datetime, self.price, u'OK' if self.valid else 'NOK')


    @property
    def date(self):
        return self.datetime.date()

    @property
    def time(self):
        return self.datetime.time()
```

The view:

```
def scans(request):
    ...
    scans = Scan.objects.filter(occurence__product=product)

    scans_table = ScansTable(scans)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(scans_table)
    scans_table.paginate(page=request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page=50)

    return render(request,"dashboard_app/scans.html",context={'scans_table':scans_table})
```

The table is being properly renderd when I don't want to sort it. When I click on time (for example), it returns:

> Cannot resolve keyword u'time' into field. Choices are: datetime,
>   groups, id, occurence, occurence_id, price, valid

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

it's strange what the type product ?? you show the Occurence model and what value it in the view

Comment: I don't understand... Product is a model which can have multiple Occurence objects.

Comment: Ok , what the value you passing what the type of that product it's a instance of product ???

Answer (score 0):

It appears that defined properties/methods of the model are not available for sorting/filtering within the queryset. I don't fully understand why that is the case. A solution would be to NOT define `date` and `time` as properties on the `Scan` model, but instead annotate them to the queryset used to populate the data.

```
from django.db import models

def scans(request):
    ...
    scans = Scan.objects.filter(occurence__product=product).annotate(
        date=models.F('datetime__date'),
        time=models.F('datetime__time')
    )
    ...
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#date) on field lookups. Also you could use the `tables` specific columns for those fields - note that you don't need to define the accessors now the results are already in the queryset:

```
class ScansTable(tables.Table):
    ...
    date = tables.DateColumn()
    time = tables.TimeColumn()
    ...
```